# its possible to use surface subdivision with vertex groups?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

there isnt a feature yet in the surfsub modifier to make its funtion in a vertex group instead of all the hole mesh. that would be very usefull for modelling a small part of a mesh that you want to detail or smooth instead of all the mesh, simply assigning the faces that you want to a group and then you would go to the modifier and set it up to affect only that vertex group.

Comment: There is no necessity for vertex groups to be contiguous set of faces, or even have any faces. How would the boundaries be generated without ngons? Consider instead the multi-resolution modifier.

Comment: You can make subdivisons in edit mode. Just select the area what you want, hit W then S (for simple) or U (for smooth). Then you can adjust the factor or the repeat count in the left side panel.

Comment: @batFINGER but multiresolution its for sculpting?

Comment: @FFeller -- does this option still exist in 3.5.1?  Not finding it.

Comment: @james_t You can find the Subdivide tool in the Edge menu in Edit mode