# Subdivision Surface on a vertex group

Tags: subdivision-surface

It would appear that [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137400/its-possible-to-use-surface-subdivision-with-vertex-groups) is not longer available in 3.5.1?

Paraphrased: "there isn't a feature Subdivision Surface modifier to limit it's effects to a vertex group instead of all the whole mesh. that would be very useful for modelling a small part of a mesh that you want to detail or smooth instead of all the mesh, simply assigning the faces that you want to a group and then you would go to the modifier and set it up to affect only that vertex group."

The answer at the time was: "You can make subdivisons in edit mode. Just select the area what you want, hit W then S (for simple) or U (for smooth). Then you can adjust the factor or the repeat count in the left side panel.".

In 3.5.1, 'w' in edit mode cycles the type of Select mechanism, and I cannot find anything int the menus.

Comment: i think that the answer given is just to right click > Subdivide

Comment: @moonboots -- but that doesn't "smooth" only some parts of the mesh: that just creates more vertices between the existing verticies.   So I guess I would have to partition the mesh I want smooth-redered into a sep obj... sigh

Comment: What is your situation exactly? When he was talking about smooth it's now the Smoothness option in the Operator Box

Comment: @james_t I would recommend you take a look at the options of the _Subdivide_ function...  some of them might be useful, not only the _Smoothness_ factor. The _Create N-Gons_ checkbox for example might be important, because when you subdivide and smooth only a part of the mesh this might make the adjacent n-gons non-planar.